# absolutely convergence in $l^2(\mathbb{N})$ space

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $x=(x_i)_{i=1}^{\infty}$  be a sequence such that for all $y=(y_i)_{i=1}^{\infty}$ $\in l^2(\mathbb{N})$
$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}|x_iy_i|< \infty $

Show that $x \in l^2(\mathbb{N})$ .

Can you please give some hint about solving this problem. I don't know even how to start it.
Thanks !